# Either $r$ or $1-r$ is left-invertible in a ring $R$ with $1$ $\iff$ either $r$ or $1-r$ is a unit.

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a noncommutative ring with $1$. I need to show that for any $r\in R$ either $r$ or $1-r$ is left-invertible if and only if either $r$ or $1-r$ is a unit.

**Proof**. Indeed, if either $r$ or $1-r$ is a unit, then either $r$ or $1-r$ is left-invertible. Conversely, it suffices to show that every left-invertible element $r\in R$ is a unit. Let $r\in R$ be left-invertible. There exists $x\in R$ such that $xr=1$.

**Case 1** . If $x$ is left-invertible, there exists $y\in R$ such that $yx=1$. Now,
\begin{align}
xr = 1 \implies yxr=y \implies r=y \implies rx=1.
\end{align}
Thus, $r$ is a unit.

**Case 2**. If $x$ is not left-invertible, it follows by the hypothesis that $1-x$ is left-invertible. Let $z\in R$ be such that $z(1-x)=1 \iff 1-z=-zx$. Notice that if $1-z$ is left-invertible, then so is $-zx$ which implies that $x$ is left-invertible, a contradiction. By the hypothesis, $z$ is left-invertible with left-inverse $z'$ (say). Hence,
\begin{align}
z(1-x) = 1 \implies z'z(1-x)=z' \implies 1-x=z' \implies zz'=1. 
\end{align}
That is, $z$ is a unit with inverse $1-x$. Now,
\begin{align}
r=1r=z(1-x)r=zr-zxr=zr-z \implies z=(z-1)r.
\end{align}
Observe that if $r$ is a unit, then $z-1$ turns to be a unit and thus $1-z$ is left-invertible, a contradiction.

How is that ?!. This procedure shows that I can never get I need to prove ?!. Where is the trick in my proof ?!.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The start of your second case sounds a bit fishy. Why do we know that either $x$ or $1-x$ is left invertible? Aren't we trying to show that with $r$ or $1-r$ left invertible, one of them is a unit, $x$ doesn't really seem to play into that.

Comment: No. 
In the second half of the proof (the converse) I show that if either $r$ or $1-r$ is left-invertible for every $r\in R$, then either $r$ or $1-r$ is a unit for every $r\in R$. By the hypothesis, if $x$ is not left-invertible, then $1-x$ must be left-invertible. @linkja

Comment: Then you should maybe reformulate your hypothesis, because right now it is just the equivalence $1-r \text{ or } r \text{ left-invertible} \iff 1-r \text{ or } r \text{ invertible} $